# PHP: connecting calculator to GUI

Tags: php, forms, calculator

I have made a calculator in php I have tried to use a MVC design.
The calculator is working fine but I would like to connect it to a GUI.
what I have right now is the php I use to call my class followed by some html wich contain my buttons.

```
<?php
//index_input.php
require_once 'calc.php';
require_once 'opInterface.php';
require_once 'op.php';

$c=new Calculator;
$c->setOP(new Add);
$c->calc(10,50);//20
$c->setOP(new Sub);
$c->calc(30);//30
$c->setOP(new Mult);
$c->calc(5);//150
$c->setOP(new Div);
$c->calc(2);//75
//echo $c->getResult();
?>

<html >
<head>

<title>Calculator Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="?page=calc">
<!--displays tthe result-->
<input type="text" name="display" value="<?php echo $c->getResult();?>">
<div class="containor">
    <div class="opcontainer">
        <input class="operator" type="button" name="op" value="+">
        <input class="operator" type="button" name="op" value="-">
        <input class="operator" type="button" name="op" value="*">
        <input class="operator" type="button" name="op" value="/">
    </div>
    <input class="number" type="button" name="1" value="1">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="2" value="2">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="3" value="3">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="4" value="4">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="5" value="5">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="6" value="6">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="7" value="7">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="8" value="8">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="9" value="9">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="0" value="0">
    <input id="enter" type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
    <input class="number" type="button" name="clear" value="clear" >
</div>
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble in connecting the buttons to the php code. I am thinking of add some if staements for when opperators are click like so:

```
if($_POST['op'] =="+"){
    $c->setOP(new Add);
    $c->calc(10,10);//20
}
```

Is this a good way of doing this are do I need to appy differnt methodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP alone, you'd have to send the form for each button press and keep track of the calculation options throughout the session. The GUI you may be after is simply HTML + JS + CSS. With JavaScript, the user could build the entire calculation before submitting the form (submitting the whole calculation to your PHP calculator), or... bypass PHP altogether (you could build the entire calculator in JavaScript without sending a form at all).

Comment: So what I am doing in php is impossible or extremely hard to implement?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. It's just that if you wanted buttons to click to update the current formula without the help of JavaScript, you'd have to submit the form each time, and keep track of the current formula in `GET` or `SESSION`, etc. Also, it's a bit odd for UX since the page would have to reload for each button click.

Comment: So doing it in JS would be less code and wouldn't require constant refresh.  I wanted to see if I could do this with php because I thought it funny that php is used to create a dynamic page but between page loads what it display is rather static.

Comment: Well, PHP is server-side. It's really meant for handling server-side stuff. What you're talking about is mostly client-side. Each have thier roles, each can do things the other can't. They work together :) This guy made an entire (fun) game out of PHP (http://www.urbandead.com/), where every click refreshes the page. It can be done, it's just not the norm. If you appreciated my time and answer, it would be awesome if you'd accept it. :) Thanks!